# CUDA - Convert texture from int to int4

Tags: cuda, textures

I want to ask how can I convert this texture:

```
texture<int, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> text1;
```

to

```
texture<int4, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> text2;
```

So my problem is with the indexes. For example, imagine that I acceesed to the col 10 row 5 in text1 like this

```
int col 10;
int row 5;
int tex2d(text1, col, row);
```

But if I did the same, obviously I'm not accessing to the same data:

```
int col 10;
int row 5;
int4 tex2d(text2, col, row);
```

So, I tried like dividing the col / 4 and row /4, but I don't succeed either. I think that I should use DIV and MOD, but I don't know how.

Does anyone know how to access correctly using 4 channels? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only indexing you need to modify between the two cases is the horizontal (`x`) indexing.  For the `int4` case, the horizontal indexing can be divided by 4 (as compared to the `int` case) but it will retrieve 4 values.  Here is a full example:

```
$ cat t1918.cu
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <cstdio>
#define HEIGHT  7680
#ifndef USE_INT4
#define WIDTH   7245
typedef int it;
#else
#define WIDTH   1812
typedef int4 it;
#endif

cudaArray * Array_Device;
texture<it, 2,cudaReadModeElementType> Image;

__global__ void k(int x, int y)
{
  int w;
#ifdef USE_INT4
  w = WIDTH*4;
#else
  w = WIDTH;
#endif
  for (y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
   for (x = 0; x < w; x++){
    int nx=x, no=0;
#ifdef USE_INT4
    no = x&3;   //modulo by 4
    nx >>= 2;   //division by 4
#endif
    it val = tex2D(Image,nx,y);
    int rval = reinterpret_cast<int *>(&val)[no];
    if (rval != y*10000+x) {
      printf("mismatch at %d, %d, was: %d, should be: %d\n", x,y, rval, y*10000+x);
      return;
      }
    }
}


void p()
{
        it *h = new it[WIDTH*HEIGHT];
        // this dataset and test-case only works for textures up to width of 9999 for int or 2499 for int4
        for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
          for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++){
#ifndef USE_INT4
            h[i*WIDTH+j] = i*10000+j;
#else
            h[i*WIDTH+j] = {i*10000+j*4+0, i*10000+j*4+1, i*10000+j*4+2, i*10000+j*4+3};
#endif
            }
        cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<it>();
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocArray(&Array_Device, &channelDesc,WIDTH,HEIGHT ));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaBindTextureToArray(Image,Array_Device));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy2DToArray( Array_Device,
                                        0,
                                        0,
                                        h,
                                        WIDTH*sizeof(it),
                                        WIDTH*sizeof(it),
                                        HEIGHT,
                                        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

        k<<<1,1>>>(0,0);
        checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}

 int main(){
#ifdef USE_INT4
  printf("int4\n");
#endif
  p();
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc -o t1918 t1918.cu
t1918.cu(40): warning: function "tex2D(texture<T, 2, cudaReadModeElementType>, float, float) [with T=it]"
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/texture_fetch_functions.h(198): here was declared deprecated

t1918.cu: In function ‘void p()’:
t1918.cu:63:49: warning: ‘cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(const texture<T, dim, readMode>&, cudaArray_const_t) [with T = int; int dim = 2; cudaTextureReadMode readMode = (cudaTextureReadMode)0; cudaError_t = cudaError; cudaArray_const_t = const cudaArray*]’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  checkCudaErrors(cudaBindTextureToArray(Image,Array_Device));
                                                 ^
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h:1642:53: note: declared here
 static __CUDA_DEPRECATED __inline__ __host__ cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h: In instantiation of ‘cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(const texture<T, dim, readMode>&, cudaArray_const_t) [with T = int; int dim = 2; cudaTextureReadMode readMode = (cudaTextureReadMode)0; cudaError_t = cudaError; cudaArray_const_t = const cudaArray*]’:
t1918.cu:63:49:   required from here
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h:1650:55: warning: ‘cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(const texture<T, dim, readMode>&, cudaArray_const_t, const cudaChannelFormatDesc&) [with T = int; int dim = 2; cudaTextureReadMode readMode = (cudaTextureReadMode)0; cudaError_t = cudaError; cudaArray_const_t = const cudaArray*]’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return err == cudaSuccess ? cudaBindTextureToArray(tex, array, desc) : err;
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h:1603:53: note: declared here
 static __CUDA_DEPRECATED __inline__ __host__ cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h: In instantiation of ‘cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(const texture<T, dim, readMode>&, cudaArray_const_t, const cudaChannelFormatDesc&) [with T = int; int dim = 2; cudaTextureReadMode readMode = (cudaTextureReadMode)0; cudaError_t = cudaError; cudaArray_const_t = const cudaArray*]’:
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h:1650:55:   required from ‘cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(const texture<T, dim, readMode>&, cudaArray_const_t) [with T = int; int dim = 2; cudaTextureReadMode readMode = (cudaTextureReadMode)0; cudaError_t = cudaError; cudaArray_const_t = const cudaArray*]’
t1918.cu:63:49:   required from here
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h:1609:32: warning: ‘cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(const textureReference*, cudaArray_const_t, const cudaChannelFormatDesc*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return ::cudaBindTextureToArray(&tex, array, &desc);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime_api.h:8662:46: note: declared here
 extern __CUDA_DEPRECATED __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaBindTextureToArray(const struct textureReference *texref, cudaArray_const_t array, const struct cudaChannelFormatDesc *desc);
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1918
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc -o t1918 t1918.cu -DUSE_INT4
t1918.cu(40): warning: function "tex2D(texture<T, 2, cudaReadModeElementType>, float, float) [with T=it]"
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/texture_fetch_functions.h(198): here was declared deprecated

t1918.cu: In function ‘void p()’:
t1918.cu:63:49: warning: ‘cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(const texture<T, dim, readMode>&, cudaArray_const_t) [with T = int4; int dim = 2; cudaTextureReadMode readMode = (cudaTextureReadMode)0; cudaError_t = cudaError; cudaArray_const_t = const cudaArray*]’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  checkCudaErrors(cudaBindTextureToArray(Image,Array_Device));
                                                 ^
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h:1642:53: note: declared here
 static __CUDA_DEPRECATED __inline__ __host__ cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h: In instantiation of ‘cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(const texture<T, dim, readMode>&, cudaArray_const_t) [with T = int4; int dim = 2; cudaTextureReadMode readMode = (cudaTextureReadMode)0; cudaError_t = cudaError; cudaArray_const_t = const cudaArray*]’:
t1918.cu:63:49:   required from here
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h:1650:55: warning: ‘cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(const texture<T, dim, readMode>&, cudaArray_const_t, const cudaChannelFormatDesc&) [with T = int4; int dim = 2; cudaTextureReadMode readMode = (cudaTextureReadMode)0; cudaError_t = cudaError; cudaArray_const_t = const cudaArray*]’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return err == cudaSuccess ? cudaBindTextureToArray(tex, array, desc) : err;
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h:1603:53: note: declared here
 static __CUDA_DEPRECATED __inline__ __host__ cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h: In instantiation of ‘cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(const texture<T, dim, readMode>&, cudaArray_const_t, const cudaChannelFormatDesc&) [with T = int4; int dim = 2; cudaTextureReadMode readMode = (cudaTextureReadMode)0; cudaError_t = cudaError; cudaArray_const_t = const cudaArray*]’:
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h:1650:55:   required from ‘cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(const texture<T, dim, readMode>&, cudaArray_const_t) [with T = int4; int dim = 2; cudaTextureReadMode readMode = (cudaTextureReadMode)0; cudaError_t = cudaError; cudaArray_const_t = const cudaArray*]’
t1918.cu:63:49:   required from here
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h:1609:32: warning: ‘cudaError_t cudaBindTextureToArray(const textureReference*, cudaArray_const_t, const cudaChannelFormatDesc*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return ::cudaBindTextureToArray(&tex, array, &desc);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime_api.h:8662:46: note: declared here
 extern __CUDA_DEPRECATED __host__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaBindTextureToArray(const struct textureReference *texref, cudaArray_const_t array, const struct cudaChannelFormatDesc *desc);
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1918
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
int4
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

The data stored in the texture in the `int` case looks like this:

```
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7 ...
1000 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006 1007...
2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007...
3000 3001 3002 3003 3004 3005 3006 3007...
...
```

In the `int4` case it looks like this:

```
{   0,   1,   2,   3} {   4,   5,   6,   7} ... 
{1000,1001,1002,1003} {1004,1005,1006,1007} ... 
{2000,2001,2002,2003} {2004,2005,2006,2007} ...
{3000,3001,3002,3003} {3004,3005,3006,3007} ...
...
```

The kernel demonstrates how to retrieve the same value for a given `(x,y)` coordinate given to the kernel, in either case.

Note that textures are deprecated and for new work you should switch to [texture objects](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-texture-objects-improve-performance-and-flexibility/).

Comment: Thank you so much ! The only thing that I don't understand is inside the kernel, how can I know the axis (x,y,z,w) that I have to use? Maybe using MOD 4?

Comment: So what I have to achieve is that when I say val(1, 0), get the same value using int and int4 textures, in our case, both results should be 1

Comment: I've modified the code to demonstrate that.

Comment: You are incredible! Thank you so much. The only problem with this is that using this sizes

`#define HEIGHT  7680
#ifndef USE_INT4
#define WIDTH   7245
typedef int it;
#else
#define WIDTH   1812
typedef int4 it;
#endif`

and then trying to access `k<<<1,1>>>(1500,1000);`, don't match. Int texture returns 1001500 while int4 returns 0. Do you know why ? Thank you again a lot, I have been stuck with this problem for 3 weeks.

Comment: Sorry, and another problem is that if I use k<<<1, 1>>>(3968, 1000); Using int or int4 always return 0 on the kernel side.

Comment: I had an error in one of the parameters I was passing to `cudaMemcpy2DToArray`.  I've fixed that, updated the test case to match your prompt dimensions, and rewritten the kernel code so that it does an exhaustive check of all locations in the texture, to make sure the are as expected.

Comment: Robert, thank you a lot !!!!!! I could solve my problem and I understand the idea. Thank you again